# C++11 namespace lookup changed from C++98?

Tags: c++11

I have some code I made before using boost. I made my own bind function (similar to bind1st) in a "core" namespace. It used to work fine.

But when adding -std=c++11 to gcc, many uses bind are resolved to std::bind instead of core::bind, coursing compilation errors.
I can make it work by changing all uses of "bind" to explicitly "core::bind".

This happens for all code within the namespace core, in nested namespaces under core and in places, where I used "using namespace core". Even "recursive" calls to bind inside my bind implementations have the problem.

I have looked for "using namespace std" in the pre-processor output and can only find one instance inside a swap method from boost, and still it finds bind from std:: instead of core::.

Furthermore, gcc-5.3.1 is failing a lot more than gcc-4.8.4.

Comment: Could you show a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 4):

You really should have included a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), however I am going to use my psychic debugging skills, and predict that your problems involve cases where (some of) the arguments are in the `std` namespace (think `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc).

[Argument Dependant Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) means that if an argument is in the `std` namespace, then the function (`bind`) is looked for in the `std` namespace.  In C++03 it wasn't found there, so the compiler goes off to look in `core`.  In C++11 it *is* found in `std`, so the compiler uses it.

Comment: Your psychic debugging skills needs a citation.  But of course you knew that.